# Finding subset sum using dynamic programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm practicing Dynamic Programming and I'm struggling with debugging my code. The idea is to find if a sum is possible given a list of numbers. Here's my code:

```
a = [2,3,7,8,10]
sum = 11
b = list(range(1, sum+1))
m = [[False for z in range(len(b))] for i in range(len(a))]

for i, x in enumerate(b):
    for j, y in enumerate(a):
        if x==y:
            m[j][i]=True
        elif y<x:
            m[j][i] = m[j-1][i]
        else:
            m[j][i] = m[j-1][i] or m[j-i][y-x]

for i, n in enumerate(m):
    print(a[i], n)
```

And here is the output:

```
2 [False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
3 [False, True, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
7 [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, False, False, False, False]
8 [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, False, False, False]
10 [False, True, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, False]
```

As I understand it, in my else statement, the algorithm is supposed to go up 1 row and then look at the difference of x and y and check if that slot is possible. So for instance in the most obvious case, the last element in the last row. That would be 10(y)-11(x) which should go all the way back to index 1 on the row above it, which as we know it's True. Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, any help in understanding this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite follow why you need a two dimensional list...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Isn't that the dynamic programming approach for this problem?

Comment: not per se. Do you know what you are doing here? If you simply want to know if you can use the coins to sum up to a given value, you can use a 1d list.

Comment: can you reuse a coin, or can every number be only used once?

Comment: Yes @WillemVanOnsem I understand what I'm doing, the matrix on my paper makes sense. But the code isn't quite right. I could solve this using a greedy approach or the sorted left and right approach, but I"m trying to accomplish this through Dynamic Programming. It's not getting the answer that I'm interested in, moreso interested in solving this through DP

Comment: You can only use the element once.

Comment: are negative coins possible? If not, this can easily be implemented with a 1d array.

Comment: I assume you do not have to use each coin: you can decide not to use the coin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you only feed **positive values**, I don't quite follow why you need a two dimensional list. You can simply use a 1d list:

```
coins = [2,3,7,8,10]
sum = 11
```

Next we initialize the list `possible` that states whether it is possible to obtain a certain value. We set `possible[0]` to `True` since this sum can be accomplished with no coins.

```
possible = [False for _ in range(sum+1)]
possible[0] = True
```

Now you iterate over each coin, and over the list and "upgrade" the value if possible:

```
for coin in coins:
    for i in range(sum-coin,-1,-1):
        if possible[i]:
            possible[i+coin] = True
```

After that, the list `possible` shows for each value from `0` up to (and including `sum`) whether you can construct it. So if `possible[sum]` is `True`, the `sum` can be constructed.

For the given `coins` and `sum`, one gets:

```
>>> possible
[True, False, True, True, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True]
```

So values `0`, `2`, `3`, `5`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10`, `11` are constructible with the coins.

## Edit: track the coins

You can also keep track of the coins by slightly modifying the code:

```
possible = [None for _ in range(sum+1)]
possible[0] = []
for coin in coins:
    for i in range(sum-coin,-1,-1):
        if possible[i] is not None:
            possible[i+coin] = possible[i]+[coin]
```

Now possible looks like:

```
>>> possible
[[], None, [2], [3], None, [2, 3], None, [7], [8], [2, 7], [10], [3, 8]]
```

So `0` can be constructed with coins `[]` (no coins); `2` can be constructed with `[2]` (one coin with value `2`), `3` with `[3]`, `5` with `[2,3]`, etc.

Comment: Ah, ok I get this solution. But if I use a 1D array it's not possible to keep track of the coins used to reach to the solution, right?

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: actually it is, one simply needs to modify the code a bit.

Comment: Ah, this is a much better solution than what the algorithm books are suggesting. Thank you! I'm still not entirely sure why my code didn't work but it's much more difficult to debug than a 1d array

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat: keep in mind this only works for positive values.

Comment: I suppose it is possible to normalize the negative values if I wanted to keep this solution and apply it for negative values as well. If I adjust the "largest" negative value to be 0 and increase the sum and every other element then it's possible to keep the solution.

Comment: This algo would not give you more than one sloution right?

Comment: @KanwarMalik: that's correct. Since giving all the solutions, would remove the "reduction", and then the algorithm would again be exponential. It is not that hard to change it, but it would basically defeat the purpose of efficient querying. You can of course change the "merge" strategy, to return the "best" combination.